# How to validate an ID which should be in given array - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have an array which is

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 7,
  2 => 11,
  3 => 8,
  4 => 5,
)
```

Now I want to validate a field `status` which should be in the given list.

```
$validation = Validator::make($req->all(),[
    'status.*.id' => 'required'
]);
```

How can I validate the `status`? Can anyone suggest any solution?
Thank You.

Comment: Hold on, so this array is the value of `$request->get('status')`? And the array should contain a specific id?

Comment: @Jerodev `status` is an object array. Object ID should contain a specific value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has an option to validate a value compare to a given array of data:

```
//At the top of your class add the correct Rule namespace.

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$yourarray = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 7,
    2 => 11,
    3 => 8,
    4 => 5,
];

$validation = Validator::make($req->all(),[
    'status.*.id' => ['required',Rule::in($yourarray)]
]);
```

For further details follow the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
    <input type="text" name="person[1][id]">
    <input type="text" name="person[1][name]">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="text" name="person[2][id]">
    <input type="text" name="person[2][name]">
</p>
```

Now you can validate the requested data as below:

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'person.*.id' => 'exists:users.id',
  'person.*.name' => 'required:string',
]);
```